# LDA followed by multiple PLS models OR PLS2 to include both the continuous dependent variable and the categorical variable

Tags: discriminant-analysis, partial-least-squares

I have 1200 spectral Xvariables.
I use PLS-LDA to reduce Xvariables and classify them in groups (contaminants).
After that I need to quantify the "amount" of contaminant by PLS.
First I tried to plug in the output of the PLS-LDA in PLS as Xvariable (using dummy variables).
But then I realized (and also found out from the output), that the "contaminant" variable has no influence on the Yvariable "percentage" (both of them were just chosen in the experimental setup). As such my PLS output shows that the "loadings" of these dummy variables are basically ZERO, so they are not considered which makes sense.
HOWEVER, the variable "contaminant" does obviously show in the variability of the Xvariables (which I used to to LDA).
If I just neglect the variable "contaminant" I can make a somewhat good PLS model (even pretty good after external validation), but when I plot my MEAN (mean for each contaminant and percentage) outcomes (see pic), then it is pretty clear that there is some difference in prediction among the groups. So the logical thing would be (I think) to use "multiple PLS models". So for each group of "Contaminant" I make a separate PLS model and then  I just send the output of the PLS-LDA to a model based on the classification (so I include the chance of error classifcation here) and then predict the percentage "Contaminant".
But the issue I have with this method is that by splitting the data to make 6 models, I have much less data to make the model, so it becomes less believable and less predictive.

So, with all this said, here is my question:
Is there a way for me to include the "Contaminant" variable among the Yvariables, such as in "PLS2"? Or is this technique not meant for this type of situation?
I am basically trying to find something that I can do to avoid having to split my data into 6 parts.

Additional question: Is there any theoretical point in using "PLS-DA" instead of "PLS-LDA" for classification here because I ran both of them in R and I do not see much difference really.

Anyway, thank you for considering my question and have a nice day!

[image: Mean values of Prediction(Percentage~LVs of spectra) (of general model without considering Contaminant) versus measurement for all groups of Contaminant]